# C# Sql Connection String Across Pages

Tags: c#, sql, connection-string

If I have several pages what would be the correct procedure in creating a connection string variable and sharing it among all of my pages. I would prefer not to type the connection string 100 times for each page and would just rather call it. Can I create it in my namespace or whats the best approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the connection string in the web.config file. See the following on MSDN: [How to: Read Connection Strings from the Web.config File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx)

Example of connection string in config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Movies2"
         connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Movies;User ID=wt3movies;Password=lalalalala;Integrated Security=SSPI"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Using the string:

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Movies2"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's typically in your configuration file (web.config)

Answer (score 1):

can't you use the `<connectionStrings/>` configuration ?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well i would have included Setting file and placed it over there.It may be not the best bet but works for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options. It depends on what data access methodology you are using. I would suggest creating a class to handle loading the connection string from the web.config file and exposing it as a public property.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to approach this which would delve in to architecture/SOC/IoC/Repository/ etc, but to answer your question in its simplest possible sense, you could create a Database class that had a single method that fetched your connection string from configuration.

```
internal class DataAccess
{
   static string GetDatabaseConnection()
    {
      return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppDb"].ConnectionString;
      // where AppDb is defined in your web.config/app.config.
    }
}
```

Your pages could just use:

```
string connection = DataAccess.GetDatabaseConnection();
```

Answer (score 0):

connection strings are usually stored in configuration files such as the web config.  Here is a simple example
add something like this to the config

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add 
    name="NorthwindConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial 
    Catalog=Northwind;Persist Security Info=True;User 
    ID=userName;Password=password"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  />
</connectionStrings>
```

and then retrive it as

```
System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig =
            S

ystem.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/MyWebSiteRoot");
            System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connString;
            if (rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0)
            {
                connString =
                    rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString"];
                if (connString != null)
                    Console.WriteLine("Northwind connection string = \"{0}\"",
                        connString.ConnectionString);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("No Northwind connection string");
            }
```

full article is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should keep it in you config file. For winforms that will be app.config, and for webforms it's web.config. Here is the section you need to have (for winforms).

`<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyNameSpace.Properties.Settings.ConnectionString1"
   connectionString="Data Source=MYSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;Integrated Security=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>`

Then you can access the connection string like this (depending on your .NET version - this is for 2.0)

`string connectionString = ((string)(configurationAppSettings.GetValue(ConnectionString1"", typeof(string))));`

Answer (score 0):

Have the connection string (CS) in `(App/Web).Config` file and have the CS returned from a static method `GetConncectionString()`.It means, this particular static method would be used in all the pages where CS is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a file called connectionStrings.config,or a name you choose, with this content:

```
    <connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="server=MyServer; database=MyDataBase; user id=myUser; pwd=MyPwd;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

And then, in your Web.Config
Insert this tag under  node

```
<connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config"/>
```